# Proving that product of some sets is nonempty

Tags: measure-theory

Let $Z = \{ (x,y) \in [0,1] \times [0,1]: x-y \in \mathbb{Q} \}$ and let $A,B \subset [0,1]$ be a sets with positive Lesbegue measure. How can I prove that $\lambda_2(Z) = 0$? Also i have to prove that $Z \cap (A \times B) \neq \varnothing$

My intuition for first problem was following: for every $x \in [0,1]$ we have countable $y \in [0,1]$ such that $x-y \in \mathbb{Q}$. Unfortunetely I can choose every $x$ from $[0,1]$ and I can't get that Z is countable (I think it is so).

In second problem I think it will be good idea to use Steiner Theorem (for algebraic sum), but I haven't got enough skill to do it.

Comment: $Z$ is the union of countably many lines $x-y=q$. Can you prove that a line has measure zero?

Comment: Line has measure zero because it is a countable sum of segments (every segment has measure zero - we can choose coverage of rectangles with size $\to 0$). Thank you.

Comment: For the second problem you need to show that, If $A,B\subset[0,1]$ are sets with positive Lebesgue measure, then the set $A-B:=\{a-b:a\in A,\ b\in B\}$ contains an interval (which of course contains a rational number).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that a countable union of sets of measure zero (which is the case for a segment in a square) is a set of measure zero is enough here.